# My constant UI animation blocks other UI events

Tags: ios, uiview

I want my background of the VC to change color consistently , the problem is that the rest of the UI is blocked and not responsive to any events. Ive tried also to make that animation in another thread thinking that might be the problem, but same result.

Im missing something very basic here, thanks for the help:

```
- (IBAction)shareBtn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"shared pusshed"); // not working
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: HUGE_VAL];
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses: NO];
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:9.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            }];
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5f relativeDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }];
        } completion:nil];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update UI
    });
});
```

Comment: UIKit should not be called from a background thread. What those `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_sync` staffs are doing in your code???

Comment: Ok, as i said i tried it, i removed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the dispatch statements and add UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to your animation options,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount: HUGE_VAL];
        //[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses: NO]; this line isn't necessary
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:9.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            }];
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5f relativeDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }];
        } completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can not address UIKit from background threads, meaning all the code inside of `dispatch_async` should be performed on the main thread

Comment: How this can be an answer to the actual problem!! And by the way, UIKit should not be called from background thread but that is not a MUST in most of the cases.

Comment: it's like saying that unrestricted multithreaded access to the mutable storage is not a problem 99% of the cases:), good luck debugging that 1%